# How do I programmatically set up multiple default flags?

Tags: 7, flags

How do I programmatically set up multiple default flags?

The [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1748148#default-flags) shows how to create a single flag using `mymodule_flag_default_flags()`. If I need two or three default flags for my custom module, how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. To have multiple default flags you simple do this:

```
function mymodule_flag_default_flags() {

$flags = array();

$flags[‘FLAG_NUMBER_1’] = array(
    'content_type' => 'node',
    'title' => '',
     // Rest of flag data
);

$flags[‘FLAG_NUMBER_2’] = array(
    'content_type' => 'node',
    'title' => '',
     // Rest of flag data
);

return $flags;

}
```

where `[‘FLAG_NUMBER’]` is the machine name for the flag.